# Heroku hangs for 54 minutes then errors with RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm not sure why, but `git push heroku master` works fluidly/expectedly until:

```
remote:        Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 67 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Post-install message from sass:
remote:        
remote:        Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
remote:          primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
remote:          sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
remote:        
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (211.55s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
```

Then it hangs here for 10+ minutes. I eventually pressed <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to cancel and tried again, and am currently waiting again, this time with a timer: <strike>8 minutes</strike> <strike>14 minutes</strike> <strike>18 minutes</strike> <strike>30 minutes</strike> <strike>40 minutes</strike> a total of 54 minutes (from when 'Detecting rake tasks' first appeared)

Then

```
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (211.55s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

#### Notes

```
heroku status
Apps:      No known issues at this time.
Data:      No known issues at this time.
Tools:     No known issues at this time.
```

#### Versions

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]


rails --version
Rails 6.0.3.6


bundler --version
Bundler version 2.1.4


heroku buildpacks
=== myappname Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git#heroku-16
2. heroku/ruby
3. https://github.com/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-cairo.git
4. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome.git
```

Comment: Do you have more logs or is this the only thing?

Comment: @Joel_Blum yep, that's all I see https://imgur.com/a/UHAh5Sq

Comment: I think Heroku may log more stuff than what you see when doing git push https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: @Joel_Blum thanks, I didn't think of that. I'll check now and update the question with any findings

Comment: @Joel_Blum the status in the dashboard says "build in progress", and the logs are exactly as they appear in the terminal, right up to the last lines

Comment: damn that sucks. Does your build have a new migration? it sometimes happens that they get stuck

Comment: @Joel_Blum It just failed after 54 minutes (I added the output to the question). It doesn't have any new migrations, but I did update all the gems, updated the buildpacks, and updated the stack.

Comment: Have you added any custom rake tasks? Maybe there is some kind of a circular reference that is causing this to hang?

Comment: @engineersmnky there are 2 rake tasks, both worked well prior to this deployment. Since I haven't made any changes to them, I don't think they would be the cause. I guess I could delete them and try to redeploy so as to eliminate one possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this, but worked around it by upgrading from cedar-14 stack to heroku-18 stack.

Comment: If you had mentioned your heroku stack in the question I would have immediately pointed you to [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-stack#using-cedar-14). They are currently decommissioning the 16 stack (just had to upgrade) but 14 has been closed for deployment for about 6 months (November 2020)

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky - yeh, it seems obvious with hindsight. The buildpacks were hairy too, 3 (of 5 total) were from obscure part of github with very few users. Managed to upgrade everything to heroku-18 so should be good for some time now. Thanks again for the help